# Setup a callback after a transaction has committed

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm trying to achieve something that I guess has a simple answer but somehow I can't find it reading the source code of `ember-data`.

I would like to trigger an action after a particular set of modifications have been committed to the datastore. This my current code:

```
var transaction = App.store.transaction();
user = App.get('currentUser');
transaction.add(user);
user.set('name', "Michael Jackson");
transaction.commit();
App.navigate('dashboard');
```

My first attempt was to add an observer over this user's `isDirty` property, but a) it doesn't seem idiomatic and more importantly b) I would have to remove manually that observer at the end - that's prone to errors if some exception raises in between and doesn't get removed, for instance.

Any ideas? How would you do this?

Answer (score 6):

You can use didCreate and didUpdate on the model. I'm assuming you have a user model so something like:

```
MyApp.User = DS.Model.extend({
  first: DS.attr('string'),
  page: DS.attr('string'),
  didUpdate: function() {
    //Do something
  },
  didCreate: function() {
    //do something
  }
});
```

Comment: Wow. I feel so stupid. Didn't find this before :| - it's right on the readme!! 

https://github.com/emberjs/data#record-lifecycle

Thanks!!

Comment: The thing is, this logic doesn't belong to the model itself. It should belong to that specific context.

Ember recently introduced a one-time event callback that might be useful in this case: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/commit/1809e65012b93c0a530bfcb95eec22d972069745#L0R19

So I could easily:

model.one('didCreate', function(){whatever});

Comment: I want to create a global AJAX-loader image that only rolls when there's a commit taking place, for any model. How can this be done?

Comment: @YossiS You can use the ajaxStart and ajaxStop methods on document
`$(document).ajaxStart(function () {}).ajaxStop(function () {});`